# Cannot create a new list/site in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, silverlight

I have received a below error message while creating a new application in SharePoint 2010 such as list, library or site.

[image]

Is there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight Application is unable to connect to the WCF endpoint configured by the product for enabling Client Object Model, if Security validation is set to Off.

To resolve, in Central Administration click on **Manage Web Application**s, highlight the **problematic Web application** and click **General Settings from the ribbon**.  Scroll down to **Web Page Security Validation**  and ensure Security Validation is **On**

http://ianankers.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/error-an-unhandled-exception-occurred-in-the-silverlight-application-when-creating-sharepoint-2010-sites/